# How do I the paste the file name of the file I've open and filldown?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the filename of the file that I have opened and also want to paste this file name to end of the row.
I'm using this which is giving the file name but only places it on 1 row on a table. Also I get the file path instead of just the name. How do I trim this? Complete newbie. Thanks

`WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = FileToOpen`

I have tried the above and was expecting the rows to fill but it didn't.

Edit: here is full code

Sub Get_Data_From__File()

```
Dim WScopy As Worksheet
Dim WSdest As Worksheet
Dim desWB As Workbook
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim cRow As Long

Set desWB = ThisWorkbook
Set WSdest = desWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for Incident File", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then


    
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

    
    LastRow = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
    WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Copy
    WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("AF2:AF" & LastRow).Copy
    WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = FileToOpen
 
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End If

End Sub

Comment: Please share the code of `FileToOpen`. ` paste this file name` What's this file?

Comment: It's not really clear where you want the file name to go though?  What rows are you expecting it to fill?   Is your data in a Table/ListObject?   Where did `FileToOpen` come from?    One line of code doesn't provide much context.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the full code.

Answer (score 0):

- `RecentFiles` collection represents the list of recently opened files.
- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the current macro code is running.
- Use `Split` to extract the file name. Of course, you can use VBA string functions (`Left` and `InStrRev`) to get it too.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Application.RecentFiles property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.recentfiles?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133170)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetRecentFiles()
    Dim recentFiles As recentFiles
    Dim file, aFile
    Dim iRow As Long
    ' Get row# of the first blank cell 
    iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    If Len(Cells(iRow, "C")) > 0 Then iRow = iRow + 1
    ' Check if there are recent files
    If Application.recentFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Set recentFiles = Application.recentFiles
        ' Loop through the recent files
        For Each file In recentFiles
            aFile = Split(file.Name, "\")
            Cells(iRow, "C").Value = aFile(UBound(aFile))
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next file
        Cells(iRow, "C").Value = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Else
        MsgBox "No recent files found."
    End If
End Sub
```